# Jquery Slide Down show div with loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple complex divs with nested divs including text and images. When the page loads I am displaying 4 of the div's. A button is shown below with the option to show more. Each time the user press the show more button im using Jquery to slide down and show the next 2 divs. There are a total of 28 divs so it will be 14 rows. Once all the divs are visible the button will change to "show less" and the rest of the divs will slide up or become hidden (havnt got to this part yet)

for some reason the JsFiddle is not even working properly :(, im not the best at JavaScript. Below is the code and Jsfiddle Link. I have made simple divs in the example.

## JsFiddle

[Link To Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kenyboy9/eeuzavnn/3/)

## HTML

```
<div class="leaders">

  <div class="colum-left">

 </div>
 <div class="colum-right">

</div>
   <div class="colum-left">

  </div>
  <div class="colum-right">

 </div>
</div>

 <div class="leaders-hidden">

   <div class="colum-left">

   </div>
 <div class="colum-right">

 </div>

</div>

<div class="leaders-hidden-2">

 <div class="colum-left">

  </div>
  <div class="colum-right">

 </div>

</div>

<div class="leaders-hidden-3">

 <div class="colum-left">

</div>
<div class="colum-right">

 </div>

</div>


 <center><span style="font-size: 18pt; color: #017dc5;"><a id="showmoreleaders" class="read_btw" style="color: #017dc5;" href="#">SEE MORE</a></span></center>
```

## JS

```
var count = 0;

$(".leaders-hidden").addClass('hide');
$(".leaders-hidden-2").addClass('hide');
$(".leaders-hidden-3").addClass('hide');



$("#showmoreleaders").click(function() {
count++;
 });

if (count == 1) {
 $(".leaders-hidden").slideDown("slow", function() {
   // Animation complete.
   });
 }


 if (count == 2) {
   $(".leaders-hidden-2").slideDown("slow", function() {
   // Animation complete.
   });
 }

if (count == 3) {
  $(".leaders-hidden-3").slideDown("slow", function() {
  // Animation complete.
  });
}
```

## CSS

```
.read_btw {
  border: 1px solid #017dc5;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
 }

.hide {
display: none;
}

.colum-left {
  float: left;
  width: 48%;
  border: 1px solid #d9dada;
  margin: 0px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-right: 7.5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  height: 200px;
   }

 .colum-right {
  float: right;
  width: 48%;
  border: 1px solid #d9dada;
  margin: 0px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-right: 7.5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  height: 200px;
 }
```

## JsFiddle

[Link To Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kenyboy9/eeuzavnn/3/)

Comment: There are some typo in your code. 2nd line of JS should be hidden-2. And your html doesn't have any button code?

Comment: (OT) `<center>` tag is deprecated use CSS's `text-align: center;` instead.

Comment: its working on my wordpress site but not on js fiddle...why the divs are not hidden?

Comment: You're adding a class of `hide`, but I don't see a `.hide { display: none; }` or similar in the CSS.

Comment: Thanks so much for that, i feel silly xD thought i copied from wp style..so tired xD but my function is still not working....I have updated the ticket and the fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you go.

you had your if's outside the function so thats why it didn't work, also updated so you can hide them after they are all shown.

also i removed the href from the a tag because it was causing the page to go all the way up. if you don't have a link to go to, you shouldn't put hrefs to a tags

**HTML**

```
    <div class="leaders">

  <div class="colum-left">

  </div>
  <div class="colum-right">

  </div>
  <div class="colum-left">

  </div>
  <div class="colum-right">

  </div>
</div>

<div class="leaders-hidden">

  <div class="colum-left">

  </div>
  <div class="colum-right">

  </div>

</div>

<div class="leaders-hidden-2">

  <div class="colum-left">

  </div>
  <div class="colum-right">

  </div>

</div>

<div class="leaders-hidden-3">

  <div class="colum-left">

  </div>
  <div class="colum-right">

  </div>

</div>


<center><span style="font-size: 18pt; color: #017dc5;"><a id="showmoreleaders" class="read_btw" style="color: #017dc5;">SEE MORE</a></span></center>
```

**CSS**

```
.read_btw {
  border: 1px solid #017dc5;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.colum-left {
  float: left;
  width: 48%;
  border: 1px solid #d9dada;
  margin: 0px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-right: 7.5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  height: 200px;
}

.colum-right {
  float: right;
  width: 48%;
  border: 1px solid #d9dada;
  margin: 0px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-right: 7.5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  height: 200px;
}

.hide{
  display: none;
}

#showmoreleaders{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**JS**

```
var count = 0;

$("#showmoreleaders").click(function() {

    count++;

    if (count == 1) {
        $(".leaders-hidden").slideDown("slow", function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    }

    if (count == 2) {
        $(".leaders-hidden-2").slideDown("slow", function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    }

    if (count == 3) {
        $(".leaders-hidden-3").slideDown("slow", function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });
        $('#showmoreleaders').html('SEE LESS');
    }

    if (count == 4) {
        $(".leaders-hidden-3").slideUp("slow", function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    }


    if (count == 5) {
        $(".leaders-hidden-2").slideUp("slow", function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    }

    if (count == 6) {
        $(".leaders-hidden").slideUp("slow", function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    }

    if (count == 7) {
        $('#showmoreleaders').html('SEE MORE');
        count = 0;
    }
});

$(".leaders-hidden").addClass('hide');
$(".leaders-hidden-2").addClass('hide');
$(".leaders-hidden-3").addClass('hide');
```